# What would be the best way to create my menu in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working on the admin of my portfolio and I'm having a dilemma about my menu. The admin side of my portfolio allows me to change some general info, add, modify or delete a project. Therefore, all pages of my admin have the same menu. The menu have the following buttons: a button to change the general info and a button to add a new project. if there are projects in the database, the menu have more things, a select with the names of my projects and the two buttons to modify or delete the project.

At first, I made a form for everything about the project and an other just for the change info button, but after asking some question, I got often told that I shoudn't make any form for that and that just making link should be fine.

I like that idea, but, if I do that, how can I pass the selected project when I click on modify for exemple?

```
<a href="{{ path("modify_project") }}">
```

Here is my current code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <a href="{{ path("admin_projet_ajout") }}">Ajouter un projet</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
{% if projets | length > 0%}
    <select>
        {% for id,projet in projets %}
            <option value={{ id }}>{{ projet }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li>
             <a href="{{ path("admin_projet_modifier") }}">Modifier</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="{{ path("admin_projet_supprimer") }}">Supprimer</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

If someone have a better idea, I will be very interested to ear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After really thinking about it, The best way would be a form, since you can't change the href of the link, except with javascript and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle?

Sorry, your are right, the answer is actually this one:

```
<a href="{{ path('modify_project', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a>
```

Twig will understand that, nothing more to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks really interesting, but if I use this, I know that I can create a dropdown list with all my projects, but how would I make that when I click the button modify, for exemple,  it goes to a certain root AND that it passes the select element of the dropdown menu?

Comment: Excuse me Kévin I read your question wrong, I just added the correct answer. Hope it works for you

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is that I don't have an 'entity' variable in my template. I updated my question with my corrent code.

Comment: Where are you persisting your projects?

Comment: I'm not, I'm sending an array with the id and names of my project to my template from my controler. I fyou read my upfated code, you can see that I use it to make my select. But if theres a way to make my select by persisting my project entity, it would be way better, but istill would need to be able to check if I got at least one project in my database.